# Что включает в себя богатая доменная модель DDD?

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-jpa, ddd, дизайн-api

Не могу понять критерии богатой модели, мы туда чуть ли не всю логику по работе с сущностью добавляем или только то, что изменение одного может повлечь изменение другого, то есть например у нас есть 2 величины,а третья эта разница, мы при изменении одной, сразу пересчитываем третью.
И вот пример  есть сущность, которую создал пользователь, проверка на удаление этой сущности в доменную модель нужно положить, которая выбрасывает  exception или все таки в сервисный слой?